# Measure script execution time

Tags: linux, bash

In Bash shell, is there a simple way for me to monitor the time taken to run a script and output the time taken?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes.

```
 time script
```

Where `script` is the script to monitor the time for.

For instance, `time find ~` will output something like this (Depending on the size of your home directory, that is):

```
real    0m49.139s
user    0m0.663s
sys     0m4.129s
```

Comment: @Jason: You're welcome! I'm glad that this helped!

Answer (score 3):

I made a tic/toc timer pair utility called `ttic` and `ttoc`. [It's available here](https://gist.github.com/swarminglogic/87adb0bd0850d76ba09f).

Example use:

```
$ ttic && sleep 0.4 && ttoc
0.405
```

To avoid conflicts with an existing tic/toc pairing, an ID can be specified, here `foo`:

```
$ ttic foo && sleep 0.5 && ttoc foo
```

Or assign a random ID, like so:

```
$ id=$(ttic --unique) && sleep 0.5 && ttoc $id
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to time a chunk of code, you can do:

```
> time { sleep 3; }

real    0m3.013s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.006s
```