# how to time a process in bash?

Tags: bash, timer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Measure script execution time](https://superuser.com/questions/228801/measure-script-execution-time)

How would I time how long it takes for my script `foo.sh` to run?

I'm looking for something akin to `tic` and `toc` in MATLAB.

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/228801/measure-script-execution-time/228802#228802

Comment: have you tried wrapping your code in time {}

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Easiest way is to use [bash's integrated `time`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines), [GNU Time](https://www.gnu.org/software/time/) or another unix [`time`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=time) command implementation:

```
time ./sript.sh
```

If you're interested in ticks, you can approximate it with a little help from `/proc/cpuinfo`.

If you want to dig deeper, have a look at [`strace`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace).

Comment: `time is a shell keyword`

Comment: @Hello71 my linux `bash` does not provide a time command, it uses `/usr/bin/time`. However `zsh` does, as well as my solaris `tcsh`. So even if it's not builtin your shell, you have a time provided by your userland as a fallback. Besides, those time commands may provide a slightly different output.

Comment: @mbx: [As of version 2.0 of Bash, time became a shell reserved word, with slightly altered behavior in a pipeline.](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/timedate.html#TIMREF)

Comment: @Hello71 although reserved, on that ystem `which time` returns userland time instead of the reserved keyword warning

Comment: @mbx: `which` never does that. I'm referring to `type`.

Comment: @Hello71 not `which`, but the shell does (`zsh` and `tcsh`)

Comment: What if one wants to measure the time between multiple commands/lines?

Answer (score 5):

`time` can achieve this. In this case:

```
$ time foo.sh
```